# React Testing Library: Portals bleeding into DOM of other tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I have recently started using Vitest + React-Testing-Library to test the frontend of web application.

All was going smoothly until I added a test that opens a modal that uses the [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) library. If I set this test (I will call it Failing Test for the rest of this question) to `.skip`, then all other tests pass perfectly fine. However if I include this test, then I've noticed that the DOM from the Failing Test *bleeds* into the other tests.

Whereas I would expect the other tests to have their own normal DOM instances, every other test seems to now have the same DOM from the failing test.

```
<body
  class="ReactModal__Body--open"
>
  <div
    data-react-modal-body-trap=""
    style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"
    tabindex="0"
  />
```

I assume this is something to do with the modal appending the class `ReactModal__Body--open` to the `body` element, however beyond this I can't find out how to isolate this test?

I've attempted to use `--no-threads` to run the tests in isolation but it still appears to not work.

Wondering if anyone has encountered something similair with portal'd elements and has any advice?

Comment: Are you running your tests in Mocha watch mode or how are you running them? What does package.json look like?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, here's what I realised for those that see this in the future.

The problem wasn't actually DOM bleed (as far as I know), but rather a *different* test wasn't correctly using `await`s and thus it's async methods were still running once the test **with** the modal was still running, resulting in the overlap.

This seemed to fix it for me:

`await expect(screen.queryByText('[List not found]', { selector: 'h3' }).not.toBeNull());`

Was changed to this:

`await waitFor(() => expect(screen.queryByText('[List not found]', { selector: 'h3' })).not.toBeNull());`

The added `waitFor` ensured that test wasn't terminating before the async loading in that test was finished.